# How can I plot a boxplot with negative values in log scale in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, boxplot, logarithm

I want to compare two datasets using boxplots. However, one of the datasets has a large range (-2500 -> 1800), while the other is more compact (-45 -> 35).

[image]

To compare both correctly I wanted to have similar y-axis in both boxplots. Due to the difference in range, I tried this with logscale in hope it would yield good readability:

```
subplot(1,2,1)
boxplot(DEM)
set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')
ylim([0 1750])
subplot(1,2,2)
boxplot(DEM2)
set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')
ylim([0 1750])
```

But then Matlab ignores negative values.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Is there another way to compare both datasets with boxplots by having similar Y-axis but still good readability?

Comment: log scales have no negative. The value zero is in the infinite, below. Maybe you can stitch two log axes together or something, but I just suggest using some other strategy

Comment: Comparing two things with such different ranges should show one box being tiny. Nothing wrong with that. Your first figure is fine and correct. Except for the outliers. Plotting outliers when there are that many of them is pointless. The outliers draw attention away from what is important, the bulk of the data that is abstracted away by the box and whiskers. By definition, outliers are supposed to be rare.  Consider drawing the whiskers all the way to the max and min values instead. That way you show the 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100 percentiles of the data. The whiskers right now are not meaningful.